# Delegate of tabBarController is not been called

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, tabbarcontroller

I have a custom TabBarController with a bigger center button in it and when the user press the button it calls a function *centerButtonClicked*. It works fine, but the problem is that the delegate method *shouldSelectViewController* is not been called because I set the tabBarItem programmatically. I tried to call the delegate manually but even if I put return NO in the method it still selects the view of tabBarController. All the other tab bar items except for the custom one call the delegate method. I need to return NO to a certain view so I can display an alert view to user. Anyone has a solution to this problem?

This problem was described here but it doesn't work for me:
[How can I programmatically set selected tab of UITabBarController while also triggering shouldSelectViewController in UITabBarControllerDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676718/how-can-i-programmatically-set-selected-tab-of-uitabbarcontroller-while-also-tri)

**In the AppDelegate:**

```
CustomTabBarControllerViewController *tabBarController = [[CustomTabBarControllerViewController alloc] init];

tabBarController.delegate = [TabBarController sharedManager];
```

The  sharedManager is a class method that return a singleton of the controller.

**In CustomTabBarControllerViewController:**

```
- (void)centerButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
[self setSelectedIndex:2];

[self performSelector:@selector(doHighlight:) withObject:sender afterDelay:0];

[self.delegate centerButtonPressed:sender];

[self.delegate tabBarController:self shouldSelectViewController:[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2]];
```

}

**Updating**

In CustomTabBarControllerViewController.h I declare the follow protocol:

```
@protocol CustomTabBarControllerViewController <NSObject>

- (void)centerButtonPressed: (id)sender;

@end

@interface CustomTabBarControllerViewController : UITabBarController 

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *centerButton;

@property(nonatomic, weak) id<UITabBarControllerDelegate, CustomTabBarControllerViewController> delegate;

@end
```

This is the delegate that [self.delegate tabBarController:self shouldSelectViewController:[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2]]; refers to.

Comment: Where did you add implementation of `shouldSelectViewController`?

Comment: I implemented the delegate method shouldSelectViewController in TabBarController. It works fine for the normal buttons, but the custom one doesn't call the delegate method.

Comment: I'm sorry for late reply. You assigned delegate selector to `self.delegate` through this code `[self.delegate tabBarController:self shouldSelectViewController:[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2]];`. So, what's your `self.delagate`?

Comment: I'm sorry for later reply too. I set the delegate in the AppDelegate with the follow command: `tabBarController.delegate = [TabBarController sharedManager];`  And the method `[self.delegate tabBarController:self shouldSelectViewController:[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2]];` is just a call for the delegate method of the UITabBarController with the follow signature `- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController.` I passed `self` to the parameter UITabBarController. Thanks for reply @SeraZheng.